# rjsf with typescript, how can I access formData and event in the onSubmit handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onsubmit, react-jsonschema-forms

I am trying to submit a form using a react json schema form. I need to have access to the event object in order to to e.preventDefault().
I am quite new to typescript and cant seem to find the way to access 'event' with typescript.
Without typescript it would simply be like this.

```
const onSubmit = ({formData}, e) => console.log("Data submitted: ",  formData);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Form schema={schema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit} />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

Any help on how I can do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to access the props(inlcuding the formData) and also to access the event object

```
const onSubmit = (props, e) => console.log("Data submitted: ",  props.formData);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Form schema={schema}
        onSubmit={(props: PropsWithChildren<FormProps<any>>, e?: any) => 
                   onSubmit(props, e)} 
  />
), do
```

Thereby accessing any props and having access to the event.